# how to convert String to date and add one year to that date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have this String `29/06/2017`i want to convert it into JavaScript date and add one year to it results Should be `28/06/2018` how to do it . i have tried this

```
var MyDate = new Date('29/06/2017');
```

Output is `invalid date object` how to convert it and add one year.

Comment: Have you thought about the special case where you run this on Feb. 29th on a leap year?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to switch the Day and the Year

```
var date = new Date('29/06/2017'.split('/').reverse().join('/'));
var plusOneYear = date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear()+1);
console.log(date); // output: Fri Jun 29 2018 00:00:00
console.log(new Date(plusOneYear)); // output: Fri Jun 29 2018 00:00:00
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString()) // output: 6/29/2018
console.log(date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth+1) + '/' + date.getFullYear()); // output: 29/6/2018
```

another way is

```
var date = '29/06/2017'.split('/'); // will become [day][month][year]
var newDate = date[2] + '/' + date[1] + '/' + date[0]; // join in format you would prefer
var plusOneYear = newDate.setFullYear(newDate.getFullYear()+1);
console.log(new Date(plusOneYear));
console.log(newDate.toLocaleDateString()) // output: 6/29/2018
```

Edited

Comment: thank you its working but how can i add one year to that date and again format it to this formate 28/06/2018

Comment: Please do not parse strings with the built-in parser. Also, the OP wants the day before. Have you tried this with 29/02/2016?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the other users, i would like to let you know about another way to approach this issue.

**Moment.js**

[Documentation - Reference](http://momentjs.com/)

**What's the purpose ?**

This library is very popular among Javascript Developer because it is easy to implement and allows you to manipulate Date way more easily with provided built-in features.

Also, another interesting problem that is solved by using this library is the **internationalization.**

**Internationalization and Date**

As you may know, every language has its own way to handle and write date.
(Translated Month, Different Display, ect).

Moment.js provide a full suite of feature that allows you to deal with these easily with pre-translated words and syntax.

**How to fix your issue with Moment.js**

```
var myDate = moment("29/06/2017", "MM/DD/YYYY");
```

Furthermore you can check if your Date is valid

```
myDate.isValid();
```

And here, you can simply add a year by using :

```
myDate.add(1, 'y'); // Which stands for add a year
```

Answer (score 0):

This is two questions on one. The parsing part is answered by [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results). Once you have a Date, adding a year is straight forward but you need to account for adding a year to 29 February, which will return 1 March (since there will not be a 29 February the following year).

```js
// Simple parser for DD/MM/YYYY
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[2], b[1]-1, b[0]);
}

// Simple formatter: Date to DD/MM/YYYY
function formatDMY(d) {
  return ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' +
    ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/' +
    d.getFullYear();
}

// Add year to a Date
function addYear(d) {
  var date = d.getDate();
  d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);
  // Test if 29 Feb rolled over to 1 Mar
  if (date != d.getDate()) {
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
  }
  return d;
}

// Tests (minimal)
['29/02/2016','29/6/2017'].forEach(function(s){
  var date = parseDMY(s);
  addYear(date);
  console.log(formatDMY(date));
});
```

If you want the previous day (e.g. 30/06/2016 -> 29/06/2017) then you need to subtract a day after adding the year, which is the same as this line:

```
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
```

or you can modify the *addYear* function to do it for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
var MyDate = new Date('29/06/2017'.split('/').reverse().join('/')); 
new Date(MyDate.setYear(MyDate.getFullYear() + 1));
```

Comment: thank you its working but out put is this  Fri Jun 29 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) i need it to be 29/06/2018

Comment: @bharathRaj you can use Moment.js to format string. Like Louis mentioned in his answer.